# Difference of ORACLE database and MS ACCESS DB 2010

Tags: oracle, ms-access-2010

Just want to know what is the difference of using ORACLE database and MS ACCESS database in terms of querying or data protection. I know ORACLE is capable of accommodating big volume of data. But I don't need that since my program does not used a lot of data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "In terms of querying or data protecion" what do you mean? Oracle is a Enterpise data server. MS Access is a client side database. Oracle is far superior in every way except that it is incredibly complicated. If your program doesn not use a lot of data then from the general tone of your question I suggest you forget about using Oracle and use MS Access instead.

Comment: what is more fast when it comes to data retrieval?

Comment: That is a very general question so here is a general answer: for a small amount of records (say <10000) there is no difference. How many records do you have in your database? You should try installing Oracle and compare that to the installation of MS Access and you will quickly find that Oracle is very complicated. If you have more than say a million records or more than a few users, you start running into big problems in MS Access. Oracle is an Enterprise server database and MS Access is not. They are different leagues. From the vagueness of your question, I suggest you use MS Access.